# Django uploading multiple images

Tags: django, file-upload

Ive been trying to make this for two days now. I have created website that is capable of uploading one image file, but i would like to be able to upload more of them, that are connected to the same main model. 
This is what i have for one picture upload:
forms.py:
from django import forms

```
from .models import Exam

class ExamForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Exam
        fields = ['exam_number', 'exam_file']
        widgets = {
        'exam_number': forms.NumberInput(
            attrs={'id': 'exam_number', 'required': True,})
        }
```

Models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.template.defaultfilters import slugify
from datetime import datetime
from django.core.validators import MaxValueValidator, MinValueValidator

class Exam(models.Model):
    exam_number = models.PositiveIntegerField(validators=[MaxValueValidator(6),MinValueValidator(1)])
    exam_path = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    exam_file = models.ImageField() #i want to be able to upload more of these
    exam_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    exam_user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.exam_path

    def __int__(self):
        return self.exam_number
```

views.py:

```
def create_exam(request, letnik_id, classes_id, subject_id):
    response_data = {}
    if subject_id in SUBJECTS:
        path = letnik_id + '/' + classes_id + '/' + subject_id
        form = ExamForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
        if form.is_valid():
            exam = form.save(commit=False)
            exam.exam_user = request.user
            exam.exam_path = path
            exam.exam_file = request.FILES['exam_file']
            file_type = exam.exam_file.url.split('.')[-1]
            file_type = file_type.lower()
            if file_type not in IMAGE_FILE_TYPES:
                context = {
                'error_message': 'error',
                }
                return Http404("Napaka")
            if Exam.objects.filter(exam_path=path, exam_number=exam.exam_number):
                context = {
                'form': form,
                'error_message': 'error',
                }
                return render(request, 'tests.html', context)
            exam.save()
            return redirect('subject_id', letnik_id=letnik_id, classes_id=classes_id, subject_id=subject_id)
        context = {
        "form": form
        }
        raise Http404("error")
    raise Http404("error")
```

ive heard that it would be best to make separated model for files, but i dont know how to make views that would connect to parent(exam) model.
Help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a separate model that would look something like this

```
class ExamFile(models.Model):
      file = models.ImageField()
      exam = models.ForeignKey(Exam, null=False)
```

Then in your view, instead of adding the exam_file to the exam, you will instead use it to create this new model. This will look something like this

```
from .models import Exam, ExamFile
...
exam_file = ExamFile.objects.create(
                    file = request.FILES['exam_file'],
                    exam=exam
            )
```

For more information on fixing up the forms, you can check out the docs found [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/forms/#more-on-fields)